# Is it possible to set Windows console options for a single file?

Tags: windows-10, batch-file, console

I have a `.bat` file and want to disable *QuickEdit-Mode* for this single file:

- When I run the script and click on the window icon, I can go to the Properties, with the title showing: *`C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe` Properties*. It's clear this will change the options globally for `cmd.exe`, so all batch files will be affected.

I'm sure it's possible to set settings for a single `.bat` file, but I can't find it in Windows 10.

**Edit**:

The best solution is to use a shortcut (see comments).

Comment: Your method should indeed be the way to do it. I think the title is misleading. You should try it out and see if it works. I'm pretty sure it still works exactly like that.

Comment: I've tried it out using two scripts. Doing it the way I described it sets the options for all scripts.

Comment: What if you put `title My script` in the batch file, so that the title is adjusted, and once adjusted, change the properties?

Comment: I have added a title to both of my batch files. Maybe I have to say that I want to change the options permanently.

Comment: I did understand that you want it to stick.

Comment: @somega Modifying the `cmd` properties under a `.bat`/`.cmd` file's File Properties should only be applicable when running that specific file _(global `cmd` properties should remain unchanged)_, as this is no different than creating a shortcut to `cmd.exe` and modifying the `cmd` properties within that shortcut's File Properties - the changes would only be reflected when running `cmd` from that specific shortcut.

Comment: Ok that's it! When I create a shortcut to the batch file I can disable QuickEdit in the shortcut's properties. But it's not possible to disable QuickEdit on the .bat file directly (you must create a shortcut).

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have batch `C:\scripts\sample.cmd`, than you may run it with `start` as following, giving new console the title `no-quick-edit`.

```bat
Cmd /c Start "no-quick-edit" "C:\scripts\sample.cmd"
```

note, that if you run it from other batch or cmd console, it may be simpler

```bat
Start "no-quick-edit" "C:\scripts\sample.cmd"
```

After that you may change console properties for that exact title.

Answer (score 1):

**QuickEditOff.exe and QuickEditOn.exe**.

Copy following three files into a folder and double click the batch file. It will make a program QuickEditOff.exe.

If you want a program to turn it on change 135 to 199.

I was writing a bigger version of this when I read your post. So I deleted all other lines from it and hard coded values. When the program becomes more user friendly I'll update this post. I have a range of other console utilities that can be compiled here https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/search/label/console.

---

```
REM QuickEditOff.bat
REM This file compiles QuickEditOff.vb to QuickEditOff.exe
REM This file compiles QuickEditOn.vb to QuickEditOn.exe
REM QuickEditOff.exe turns off Quick Edit mode in the command prompt.
REM QuickEditOn.exe turns on Quick Edit mode in the command prompt.
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\vbc.exe" /target:exe /out:"%~dp0\QuickEditOff.exe" "%~dp0\QuickEditOff.vb" 
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\vbc.exe" /target:exe /out:"%~dp0\QuickEditOn.exe" "%~dp0\QuickEditOn.vb" 
pause
```

---

```
    '

QuickEditOff.vb
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports Microsoft.Win32

Public Module MyApplication 

    Public Declare Function GetStdHandle Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetStdHandle" (ByVal nStdHandle As Long) As Long
    Public Declare Function GetConsoleMode Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hConsoleHandle As IntPtr, ByRef lpMode As Integer) As Integer
    Public Declare Function SetConsoleMode Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hConsoleHandle As Long, ByVal dwMode As Integer) As Integer

    Public Const STD_ERROR_HANDLE = -12&
    Public Const STD_INPUT_HANDLE = -10&
    Public Const STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE = -11&

    'Input
    Public Const ENABLE_EXTENDED_FLAGS = &h0080
    Public Const ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT = &h0004
    Public Const ENABLE_INSERT_MODE = &h0020
    Public Const ENABLE_LINE_INPUT = &h0002
    Public Const ENABLE_MOUSE_INPUT = &h0010
    Public Const ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT = &h0001
    Public Const ENABLE_QUICK_EDIT_MODE = &h0040
    Public Const ENABLE_WINDOW_INPUT = &h0008
    Public Const ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_INPUT = &h0200
    'Output
    Public Const ENABLE_PROCESSED_OUTPUT = &h0001
    Public Const ENABLE_WRAP_AT_EOL_OUTPUT = &h0002
    Public Const ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING = &h0004
    Public Const DISABLE_NEWLINE_AUTO_RETURN = &h0008
    Public Const ENABLE_LVB_GRID_WORLDWIDE = &h0010

Sub Main()
    Dim hIn as IntPtr
    Dim Ret as Integer
    hIn  = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE)
    Ret = SetConsoleMode(hIn, 135)
    If Ret = 0 then Console.WriteLine(Hex(Ret) & " - " & err.lastdllerror)
End Sub
End Module
```

---

```
'QuickEditOn.vb
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports Microsoft.Win32

Public Module MyApplication 

    Public Declare Function GetStdHandle Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetStdHandle" (ByVal nStdHandle As Long) As Long
    Public Declare Function GetConsoleMode Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hConsoleHandle As IntPtr, ByRef lpMode As Integer) As Integer
    Public Declare Function SetConsoleMode Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hConsoleHandle As Long, ByVal dwMode As Integer) As Integer

    Public Const STD_ERROR_HANDLE = -12&
    Public Const STD_INPUT_HANDLE = -10&
    Public Const STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE = -11&

    'Input
    Public Const ENABLE_EXTENDED_FLAGS = &h0080
    Public Const ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT = &h0004
    Public Const ENABLE_INSERT_MODE = &h0020
    Public Const ENABLE_LINE_INPUT = &h0002
    Public Const ENABLE_MOUSE_INPUT = &h0010
    Public Const ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT = &h0001
    Public Const ENABLE_QUICK_EDIT_MODE = &h0040
    Public Const ENABLE_WINDOW_INPUT = &h0008
    Public Const ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_INPUT = &h0200
    'Output
    Public Const ENABLE_PROCESSED_OUTPUT = &h0001
    Public Const ENABLE_WRAP_AT_EOL_OUTPUT = &h0002
    Public Const ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING = &h0004
    Public Const DISABLE_NEWLINE_AUTO_RETURN = &h0008
    Public Const ENABLE_LVB_GRID_WORLDWIDE = &h0010

Sub Main()
    Dim hIn as IntPtr
    Dim Ret as Integer
    hIn  = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE)
    Ret = SetConsoleMode(hIn, 199)
    If Ret = 0 then Console.WriteLine(Hex(Ret) & " - " & err.lastdllerror)
End Sub
End Module
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is about the titles, don’t need to complicate, just add in your bat:

```bat
title <nul && title your text
```

For no title:

```bat
Title <nul
```

**Obs.:** This also remove/overwrite any title from:

```bat
start "title" "file.bat"
cmd /c Start "title" "file.bat"
```